# mobile dont have sim card, still (Boolean)method.invoke(cm) returns true in android

Tags: android

following code returns true even without a sim card?!
Any ideas what happened?

```
boolean mobileDataEnabled = false; // Assume disabled
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            try {
                Class cmClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
                Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
                method.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
                // get the setting for "mobile data"
                mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean)method.invoke(cm);

                Log.e("mobileDataEnabled",mobileDataEnabled+"");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Some problem accessible private API
                // TODO do whatever error handling you want here
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using this snippet maybe help to you.

```
 public static boolean checkConnectivity(Context context) {
        boolean isConnect = false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (activeNetwork != null) {
            // connected to the internet
            switch (activeNetwork.getType()) {
                case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI:
                    // connected to wifi
                    isConnect = true;
                    break;
                case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE:
                    // connected to mobile data
                   isConnect = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            // not connected to the internet
        }
        return isConnect;
    }
```